# Mysql sum with group_concat and join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've trying to solve this problem for about weeks now, but still have no answers
i want to show the total quantity of the inventory_table that has the same product barcode and show also its item description.

I have three tables

product_table

```
ID| barcode | brand    | unit   | price
1 | 1111111 | Neozep   | Tablet | 5.50
2 | 2222222 | Biogesic | Syrup  | 7.50
```

inventory_table

```
ID| batch   | Total| barcode
1 | 5555555 | 100  | 1111111
2 | 6666666 | 500  | 1111111
```

productcontains_table

```
ID| Name        | Amount | Type | barcode
1 | Paracetamol | 250    | mg   | 1111111
2 | Amoxicilin  | 20     | ml   | 1111111
```

And the output should be like this

```
Barcode | Item Description                       | Price | Total Qty | Amount 
1111111 | Paracetamol 250 mg | Amoxicilin 20 ml  | P5.50 | 600       | P3300
```

My current Sql statement but this is obviously wrong hope you can help me guys 
thanks in advance

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT productcontains_table.name ,' ',
    productcontains_table.Amount,' ',
    productcontains_table.Type
    ORDER BY productcontains_table.IDno  SEPARATOR ' | ' ) AS ItemDescription,

    product_table.product_price AS Price,
    SUM(inventory_table.inventory_total) AS TotalQuantity

    product_table.price AS Price,
    SUM(inventory_table.total) AS TotalQuantity,
    product_table.price * SUM(inventory_table.total) AS TotalAmount

   FROM inventory_table
   JOIN product_table
   ON product_table.barcode = inventory_table.barcode
   JOIN productcontains_table
   ON productcontains_table.barcode = product_table.barcode

   GROUP BY inventory_table.barcode
```

Comment: Missing a comma here ´SUM(inventory_table.inventory_total) AS TotalQuantity ,´

Comment: Yeah i just forget but that is till wrong. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed a couple of typos:

```
SELECT inventory_table.barcode,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT productcontains_table.name,' ', productcontains_table.Amount,' ', productcontains_table.Type SEPARATOR ' | ') AS ItemDescription,
   product_table.price AS Price,
   SUM(inventory_table.total)/ b.cnt AS TotalQuantity,
   product_table.price * SUM(inventory_table.total) / b.cnt AS Amount
FROM inventory_table
JOIN product_table ON product_table.barcode = inventory_table.barcode
JOIN productcontains_table ON productcontains_table.barcode = product_table.barcode
JOIN
( SELECT barcode,
       count(productcontains_table.name) AS cnt
  FROM productcontains_table )b ON b.barcode=product_table.barcode
GROUP BY inventory_table.barcode,
     product_table.price,
     inventory_table.barcode
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f372/37

Comment: there's still a problem as you can see the group_concat it has 2 names of it, it means that it also add the total amount in twice so instead of having a total amount 3300 it will be 6600 because of the group_concat having 2 names it will also affect the total amount

Comment: I think a division by `count(productcontains_table.name)` should do the job.  I can not get it to work in the fiddle tho

Comment: Sorry for asking and I'm not trying to be rude, but count in concatenation in strings? how does that make sense?